# How to compare LocalDateTime instances in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

so I'm having a little problem with kotlin `LocalDateTime`

```
val now = CurrentDateTime
val someDate = someService.someLocalDateTime
```

I have two dates as you can see and I want to know if `now` is bigger than `someDate` or not.
and also I need to know if it's bigger, how much is bigger.

i can do it by checking `year`, `month`, `day`, `minute` and `second` like this:

```
if (now.year().toString() == someDate.year.toString())
```

but it's not a good way

any suggesstions would be welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Convert Kotlin `LocalDateTime` to Java `LocalDateTime`

To convert Kotlin `LocalDateTime` to Java `LocalDateTime`, you can make use of [this function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx-datetime/kotlinx-datetime/kotlinx.datetime/to-java-local-date-time.html):

```
fun LocalDateTime.toJavaLocalDateTime(): LocalDateTime
```

> Converts this kotlinx.datetime.LocalDateTime value to a java.time.LocalDateTime value.

And then you can choose to use the following method or other suggested method to compare the converted `java.time.LocalDateTime`.

#### Compare Java `LocalDateTime`

To compare `LocalDateTime`, you can use `LocalDateTime`'s `isAfter()`, `isBefore()`, `isEqual()`.

```kotlin
import java.time.LocalDateTime

fun main() {
    val currentTime = LocalDateTime.now()
    val ytdTime = LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(1)
    println(currentTime.isAfter(ytdTime))
    println(currentTime.isBefore(ytdTime))
    println(currentTime.isEqual(ytdTime))
}
```

**Output**

```
true
false
false
```

To find the difference between `LocalDateTime`, you can use `ChronoUnit`:

```kotlin
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit

fun main() {
    val currentTime = LocalDateTime.now()
    val ytdTime = LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(1)
    val secondDifference = ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(ytdTime, currentTime)
    val minutesDifference = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(ytdTime, currentTime)
    val hourDifference = ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(ytdTime, currentTime)
    println(secondDifference)
    println(minutesDifference)
    println(hourDifference)
}
```

**Output**

```
86399
1439
23
```

Comment: im using Kotlin `LocalDateTime` and your solution is for java time.

Comment: Please see the above edit. Since it would be better to use ```java.time.LocalDateTime``` class for doing comparison, I suggest you to convert your Kotlin ```LocalDateTime``` to Java ```LocalDateTime``` and do the comparison.

Comment: solved my problem, tnx

Comment: Kotlinx LocalDateTime doesn't support arithmetic because it is ambiguous when the time zone is unspecified, which can lead to bugs from incorrect assumptions you are making. For example, 1:30 AM can be 45 minutes *after* 1:45 AM of the same day if it is right after a daylight savings time transition. If you want to stick with Kotlinx time, you can convert your Kotlinx LocalDateTimes to Kotlinx Instants and subtract those.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply convert both dates in seconds and:

- compare them to know which one is bigger
- subtract them to know how much one is bigger than the other

an example would be

```
val now = CurrentDateTime.toEpochSeconds()
val someDate = someService.someLocalDateTime.toEpochSeconds();

if(now > someDate) 
//someDate is in the past
else
//someDate is in the future or both dates are equal

val distance = now-someDate
```

hope this helps

Comment: its for java date time.
im using kotlin date time

Answer (score 2):

The standard solution to compare two Date objects is by using the compareTo() function. It returns a value

```
= 0, if both dates are equal.
< 0, if date is before the specified date.
> 0, if date is after the specified date.
```

The following program demonstrates it:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*

 
fun main() {

    val now = CurrentDateTime  // "01/21/2023" 
    val someDate = someService.someLocalDateTime // "01/21/2020"
 
    val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy")
 
    val firstDate: Date = sdf.parse(now)
    val secondDate: Date = sdf.parse(someDate)
 
    val cmp = firstDate.compareTo(secondDate)
    when {
        cmp > 0 -> {
            System.out.printf("%s is after %s", d1, d2)
        }
        cmp < 0 -> {
            System.out.printf("%s is before %s", d1, d2)
        }
        else -> {
            print("Both dates are equal")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your answer is correct bu its not for kotlin `LocalDateTime`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using kotlinx-datetime, I think you can compare them as you will do for Number or String:

```kotlin
// Check if startDate is before endDate.

val datesAreValid = startDate < endDate
```

I'm not sure it compares something using the LocalDate Object or the String that prints.
What I see is it print `"2024-02-09"` when as String.

If `<` `>` `=` on String compares case by case we can assume `"2024-02-09"` is less than `"2024-03-09"`.

It's `Years / Month / day` order and `****-**-**` good format like he will persit 2 cases all the time.